# Heartbeat System.ObjectDisposedException error with mongo C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

We are using the latest 2x MongoDB driver (2.0.0-rc0) to connect to a MongoDB replicaset (3.0.1).
From time to time the driver will crash with the following error (received in the windows eventslogs):

```
Source:ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0

An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT/BACKEND_DEVELOP

Process ID: 2344

Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException

Message: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'ClusterableServer'.

StackTrace:    at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ClusterableServer.ThrowIfDisposed()
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ClusterableServer.RequestHeartbeat()
   at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.MultiServerCluster.RequestHeartbeat()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
   at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
```

What could be the problem? Problem in the driver?

Comment: If the driver crashed, then it's possible. Verify you're not disposing of the object too early first. Then, would you file a bug with the [Mongo C# Driver JIRA project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP)? Please post the issue key on the SO question.

Comment: Issue [CSHARP-1227](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1227)    created on JIRA